# How to add event handler on submenu item click of MenuStrip

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I am pulling values from databases and adding it in sub menu. i wanted to know how to i add an event handler on sub menu items so that if some body clicks shows as a message box (for example)
Below is the code but it keep on giving me main menu item instead of sub menu.

```
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    'Sql Query for getting business locations
    While reader.Read()
        DatabaseToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(reader(0)) 'adding business to menustrip main menu item (Databse)
    End While

   AddHandler MenuStrip1.Click, AddressOf ItemClicked
End Sub

Private Sub ItemClicked(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    MessageBox.Show("Test")
End Sub
```

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add event handler for `MenuStrip1`, it will work for `MenuStrip1` click

```
AddHandler MenuStrip1.Click, AddressOf ItemClicked
```

You need to add event handler for **Sub Menus**,

```
AddHandler SubMenu1ToolStripMenuItem.Click, AddressOf ItemClicked
AddHandler SubMenu2ToolStripMenuItem.Click, AddressOf ItemClicked
```

**UPDATED:**

```
While reader.Read()
    Dim SubMenu As New ToolStripMenuItem
    SubMenu.Text = reader(0)
    AddHandler SubMenu.Click, AddressOf ItemClicked

    DatabaseToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(SubMenu) 
End While
```

Comment: Sub items that i am adding are dynamic meaning i don't have exact count atm. then how?

Comment: so, show your code of adding sub menus ... edit your question

Answer (score 1):

The Add method used to add the menu item to its parent is overloaded and you should use the one that allows you to specify the Click event handler at the same time:

```
parentMenu.Items.Add(textToDisplay, imageToDisplay, AddressOf MethodToHandleClick)
```

or

```
parentMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(textToDisplay, imageToDisplay, AddressOf MethodToHandleClick)
```